# Gulp 4 watch task is not detecting changes

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-4

I am trying to switch to Gulp version 4 from Gulp version 3 and I am constantly having issues with watch task, it will not detect changes when the tracked SCSS file is changed. I made a simple example of the watch function since it is easier for debugging.

```
Ubuntu 17.10
Node v8.9.4
Npm 6.9.0
Gulp CLI version: 2.2.0
Gulp Local version: 4.0.2
```

I tried removing gulp and gulp-cli completely and installing it again, removing node_modules folder and creating package.json file from scratch but the result is the same. "Starting 'watch'..." and nothing else.

**package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"
      }
    }
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const {src, dest, watch} = require('gulp');
const sass= require('gulp-sass');

function style() {
    return src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(dest('./css'));
}

function watchTask() {
    watch('./scss/**/*.scss', style);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watchTask;
```

Note: Style task is working correctly and moving all `.scss` files from source to destination.

I really appreciate any help since I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Assuming you are running `gulp watch` try slightly modifying to `watch('./scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series(style));`  and add `series` to your require.  Sometimes this seems to help although it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Your original code works perfectly fine for me.  Those paths are correct?  And relative to the location of this gulpfile.js?

Comment: Looks like issue appears only when there is some type of mapped/synced folders with vagrant/docker. I was using vagrant and {usePolling: true} made my day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gulp watch detects changes after it boots up, not between this run and last run of `gulp watch`.

You need to tell gulp watch to run the first style task regardless.

```
function watchTask() {
  watch('./scss/**/*.scss', {ignoreInitial: false}, style);
}
```

Then it will re-run style task whenever you touched some scss file again.

**Update:**

Are you using files on docker or a network mapped disk? You might need to turn on `{usePolling: true}` as documented "needed for successfully watching files over a network or other non-standard situations. "

Comment: By adding {ignoreInitial: false} option it runs "style" task initially and that is fine now. But I still have problem when I make some change to .scss file, it will not detect changes and execute "style" task again.

Comment: adding {usePolling: true} to watch configuration worked in my case. Btw I am using vagrant synced folders. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `{usePolling: true}` was also necessary in my case, despite all files being local! I have 4 `watch` calls in my `watchTask`. When I only have 2 - they work perfectly, with 4 - I need polling...

Comment: @DziadBorowy if you use npm v8, try force it to use latest chokidar. https://github.com/aurelia/new/commit/36f4471f16be6cc2095a7d11c21a0eb524d43abd